# Hide Banner Ad with isHidden = true

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I am currently calling an Banner Ad from admob with the following code in my GameViewController.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
var bannerView: GADBannerView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX"  // Default Google Test Ad Address
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    bannerView.isHidden = false // <----- This works, but doesn't work in GameScene.swift
```

and this is the function that is called from the code above (also in GameViewController) to display the ad.

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
   bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.addSubview(bannerView)
   view.addConstraints(
     [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                         attribute: .bottom,
                         relatedBy: .equal,
                         toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                         attribute: .top,
                         multiplier: 1,
                         constant: 0),
      NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                         attribute: .centerX,
                         relatedBy: .equal,
                         toItem: view,
                         attribute: .centerX,
                         multiplier: 1,
                         constant: 0)
     ])
   }
```

This code works and displays the test ad. However, in GameScene.swift when I press a button I run this code to try hide the ad.

```
GameViewController().bannerView.isHidden = true
```

This causes the app to crash with "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". And if I change it, it won't crash, but the ad won't hide.

```
GameViewController().bannerView?.isHidden = true
```

Yet in GameViewController, if I simply change the value of isHidden to true, then it works.

```
bannerView.isHidden = true
```

Anyway to be able to hide the banner ad from the GameScene.swift when I press the button?

Comment: This creates a new instance, GameViewController(). You need to get the instance that already exists.

Comment: It's because your bannerView is nil at that time, show me snippet of your GameViewController how you hold reference to bannerView.

Comment: var bannerView: GADBannerView! which is declared in GameViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling `GameViewController()` you  are creating a new instance of `GameViewController`.

On `GameViewController().bannerView` you are accessing the `bannerView` from this new instance, and since it's an optional value which was not set on this instance, when you try to access it - will result in a crash.

What you need is to have access the main `GameViewController`, where you had the `bannerView` set.

There are two simple methods to call `GameViewController` functions from other classes: through a `delegate` or by making the class instance `static`.

```
//   DELEGATE
//
// You have access only to the functions you declared inside the procotol. 
// Only the classes that conforms to that protocol have access to the functions.
//
// GameViewController.swift

protocol GameView_Delegate
{
    func hide_ads()
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameView_Delegate
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

    //   ... 

    if let view = self.view as! SKView?
    {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
        {        
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // pass protocol reference
            scene.gv_delegate = self
        }

        view.presentScene(scene)
     }

    // ...

    }

    func hide_ads()
    {
        // hide ads code

        bannerView.isHidden = true
    }
}

// GameScene.swift

class GameScene: SKScene
{
    var gv_delegate : GameView_Delegate!

    func settings()
    {
        // call function hide_ads from GameViewController
        gv_delegate.hide_ads()
    }

    func lost_scene()
    {
        let transition = SKTransition.fade(with: UIColor.white, duration: 1.0)
        let next_scene = LostScene()
        next_scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        next_scene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
        next_scene.size = self.size

        // before moving to next scene, we must pass the delegate, so we
        // don't  lose the connection with the GameViewController
        next_scene.gv_delegate = gv_delegate
        self.view?.presentScene(next_scene, transition: transition)
    }
}

// LostScene.swift

class LostScene: SKScene
{
    var gv_delegate : GameView_Delegate!

    func settings()
    {
        // call function hide_ads from GameViewController
        gv_delegate.hide_ads()
    }

    func game_scene()
    {
        let transition = SKTransition.fade(with: UIColor.white, duration: 1.0)
        let next_scene = GameScene()
        next_scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        next_scene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
        next_scene.size = self.size

        // before moving to next scene, we must pass the delegate, so we
        // don't lose the connection with the GameViewController
        next_scene.gv_delegate = gv_delegate
        self.view?.presentScene(next_scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

When you enter a new scene, for example `LostScene`, the old scene `GameScene` in our case is deallocated (all variables emptied, all references destroyed) and a new `GameScene` instance is created and displayed on screen. Before transitioning to the new scene, you should pass the reference so you don't lose the connection with the `GameViewController` (as in my example).

```
// STATIC
//
// the properties and functions are available from everywhere
//
// GameViewController.swift

class GameViewController: UIViewController
{
    static var shared : GameViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GameViewController.shared = self

        // ...

    }

    func hide_ads()
    {
        // hide ads code
        bannerView.isHidden = true
    }
}


// GameScene.swift

class GameScene: SKScene
{
    func settings()
    {
        // call function hide_ads from GameViewController

        GameViewController.shared.hide_ads()
        // or GameViewController.shared.bannerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new instance of `GameViewController` and toggling it's `bannerView`'s `isHidden` property. You should toggle the `isHidden` property of the `bannerView` of `GameViewController` instance that you're displaying.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the "var bannerView: GADBannerView!" which is created inside GameViewController, and use it in GameScene.swift

Comment: Use the instance of `GameViewController` that you're using in `GameScene` to access the `bannerView`. Like `gameViewController.bannerView.isHidden.toggle()` in `GameScene` where `var gameViewController: GameViewController` is given in `GameScene`. You might wan't go through a few tutorials on how to pass info between ViewControllers to understand this in depth.

Comment: Thanks. I sorta of get what you mean. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, this is the solution I found to hide the banner:

"Handle all the banner stuff in the GameViewController.swift file. Inside there, assign a tag value for the bannerView variable. Then when the scene loads, load the bannerView using the tag id, then set its .isHidden property to true"

GameViewController.swift

```
bannerView.tag = 100
```

GameScene.swift

```
// hide banner
let bannerView = self.view?.viewWithTag(100) as! GADBannerView?
bannerView?.isHidden = true

// show banner
let bannerView = self.view?.viewWithTag(100) as! GADBannerView?
bannerView?.isHidden = false
```